# Connectivity between pods works inside the cluster, but not in the browser

Tags: kubernetes

For some reason, I can't establish connectivity between frontend exposed externally on host IP and backend that runs internally only.

The whole application is configured in the following way:

frontend pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: plg-frontend-pod
  labels:
    name: plg-frontend-pod
    app: playground-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: plg-frontend
    image: localhost:5000/frontend:1.32
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    env:
    - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST
      value: "http:\/\/$BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST"
    - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT
      value: "4040"
```

frontend service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: plg-frontend
  labels:
    name: plg-frontend-service
    app: playground-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30123
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: plg-frontend-pod
    app: playground-app
```

backend pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: plg-backend-pod
  labels:
    name: plg-backend-pod
    app: playground-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: plg-backend
    image: localhost:5000/backend:1.28
    ports:
    - containerPort: 4040
    env:
    - name: NODE_ENV
      value: "dev"
    - name: REDIS_HOST
      value: "redis"
```

backend service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: plg-backend
  labels:
    name: plg-backend-service
    app: playground-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4040
  selector:
    name: plg-backend-pod
    app: playground-app
```

Sending request from inside of the frontend container to the backend's endpoint works:

```
/ # curl -X POST http://10.233.62.29:4040/api/v3/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"userdata": {"lgn": "abre", "psw": "que"}}'

{"msg":"User does not exist in the database"}
```

Meanwhile in the browser:

```
POST http://10.233.62.29:4040/api/v3/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Ports are open in the firewall settings.

How to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: That is because when you do not specify the service type in your yaml file, you get the default type which is `ClusterIP`...if you want to check it from an external network(external to your k8s cluster) you need other ypes of services, like `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`

Comment: It works as expected. Your backend service is not exposed outside the cluster, therefore you can't reach it directly from outside. Does `frontend` work correctly? Is it able to communicate with `backend` via clusterIP?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to connect to a Pod IP/port from outside the cluster. This simply does not make any sense.

You need to use the Service IP/port in order to do so.
In your case, you have a `NodePort` service that exposes your backend on port 30123 in every node.

If you don't have any firewall blocking it, you should be able to get access to your backend from your browser by using hostname:

> http://:30123